# how to find a holiday based on an array and structures

Tags: c++, arrays, structure

I am trying to go through this struct, and get a holiday based on an array and Ive tried everything and It wont work to find a holiday like on 1 11 is a holiday..
Everything is right except for the function

```
 const int MAX_DATES = 60,     // Max number of holidays in list 60
 MAX_NAME_LEN = 81;  // Max length of holiday name 81

#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace::std;


// Definition of DayData type
struct DayData
{
int month,                    // Month / day of holiday
    day;
char holiday[MAX_NAME_LEN];   // Name of holiday
};

// Function prototype
 void findHoliday(const DayData holidayList[], int listLength,
int month, int day, char holidayCopy[]);

void main()
{
DayData holidayList[MAX_DATES];   // List of holidays
int count = 0,                    // Number of holidays in list
    searchMonth,                        // Input month / day
    searchDay;
char holidayName[MAX_NAME_LEN];   // Name of selected holiday

                                  // Open the designated file for input.
ifstream holidayFile("D:\\c++ class week 
2\\final\\ConsoleApplication37\\ConsoleApplication37\\holidays.txt");
if (!holidayFile) {
    cout << "Can NOT open file " << endl;
    return;
}

// Read in the list of holidays.
while (holidayFile.good() && holidayFile >>
    holidayList[count].month >> holidayList[count].day)
{
    holidayFile.get();   // Remove blank after day from the stream
    holidayFile.getline(holidayList[count].holiday,
        MAX_NAME_LEN, '\n');  // Read holiday name
    count++;                       //    including spaces
}

// Close the file.
holidayFile.close();

// Prompt the user for the date of the desired hoilday.
cout << endl << "Enter the month and day for a holiday: ";
cin >> searchMonth >> searchDay;

// Display the holiday (if any) for the requested date.
findHoliday(holidayList, count, searchMonth, searchDay, holidayName);
if (holidayName[0] != '\0')
    cout << holidayName << endl;
else
    cout << "No holiday listed" << endl;
}


void findHoliday(const DayData holidayList[], int listLength,
int month, int day, char holidayCopy[])
{
int i;
int j = 0;
for (i = 0; i < listLength; i++) { // for how many elements are in the array

    if ((holidayList[i].month == month) && (holidayList[i].day == day)) {
        // this line is the problem line below
        strcpy(holidayCopy, holidayList[i].holiday);

    } else {
            holidayCopy[j] = '\0';
        }
    }


} // end findHoliday
```

Comment: Please indicate what the function is suppose to do ( how it finds a holiday, how the parameters are supposed to be used ... ). Also, we may need to know what DayData type is ( how is it defined... )

Comment: @HatsuPointerKun i added the rest of the program

Answer (score 0):

You should `return` after you find a holiday, otherwise the result will be overrided.

```
void findHoliday(const DayData holidayList[], int listLength,
int month, int day, char holidayCopy[])
{
int i;
int j = 0;
for (i = 0; i < listLength; i++) { // for how many elements are in the array

    if ((holidayList[i].month == month) && (holidayList[i].day == day)) {
        // this line is the problem line below
        strcpy(holidayCopy, holidayList[i].holiday);
        return; // break also works

    } else {
            holidayCopy[j] = '\0';
        }
    }


} // end findHoliday
```

Comment: but why do you need a return statement if it says void?

Comment: That means you terminate the function at the point of `return` without running the following codes.

Comment: Or use `break` is clearer. That will mean you jump out of the for-loop at the point of `break`, meaning you won't consider other dates in the list because you've found the one you want.